# What is a contour integral, and how do you calculate one?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, contour-integration

So, I am currently learning Multivariable Calculus, and I know how to evaluate integrals and derivatives, as well as how to parametrize multivariable functions, and how to evaluate line integrals. I am now wondering how to evaluate contour integrals. I've checked everywhere, including here, but the answers were lengthy and hard to understand, so I didn't grasp any of the information provided. So, I resorted to asking my own question. I would like a plainly stated explanation of this, along with a formula, if possible, along with the derivation of that formula, and an explanation of what's going on when we do the math.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe try to be more specific in what part of this topic you dont understand? I am sometimes lazy to read lenghty technical stuff, but sometimes it is the only thing you can do to start with a topic.

Comment: I really don't know what I'm looking for specifically, other than a general understanding of this concept.

Comment: Briefly: In the usual terminology, these are line integrals of *complex differentiable* ("holomorphic" or "analytic") complex-valued functions over closed curves in the complex plane. To evaluate them directly, you use the techniques you know (parametrize the curve, etc.). However, complex analysis courses will show you beautiful theory with alternative ways of evaluating them.

Comment: You could try having a look at [these](https://dec41.user.srcf.net/h/IB_L/complex_methods) notes, or [these](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/us248/Lectures/Notes/shortcomplex.pdf) ones, for discussion of definitions and how to calculate. There's not a huge amount of discussion of the underlying motivation, but honestly it's quite similar to line integrals. You can think of the $\gamma'(t)$ term as a "change-of-variables" term, that lets you change a $\mathrm dz$-integral into a $\mathrm dt$-integral, when $z$ depends on some real parameter $t$.

Comment: Or [these](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/us248/Lectures/Notes/complexmethods.pdf) ones, which are a more fleshed out version of the second one, with some more discussion of motivation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we parameterize a path $\gamma$ in $\Bbb C$ with some real parameter, so $\gamma$ runs from $t=t_i$ to $t=t_f$. The contour integral of $f(z)$ along $\gamma$ is then $\int_{z(t_i)}^{z(t_f)}f(z(t))dz(t)=\int_{t_i}^{t_f}f(z(t))z^\prime(t)dt$. In this sense, it's not fundamentally different from integrals along an interval in $\Bbb R$. A common example is anticlockwise around the circle $|z-a|=r$, giving $\oint_\gamma f(z)dz=\int_0^{2\pi}f(a+re^{it})ire^{it}dt$.

If $f=\frac{1}{z-a}$, this is $\int_0^{2\pi}idt=2\pi i$, which is nonzero even though the path is closed. (Under [certain conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) not applicable here, an integral around a closer contour would be $0$, just as $\int_b^bg(x)dx=0$ for "conventional" integrals.) [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)) is the basis for how we typically calculate contour integrals. [The basic idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) is that a loop around a pole $z=a$ of a function $f$ contributes to the integral around that loop, in proportion to the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z-a}$ in an expansion of $z$. (Other powers don't matter, because $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{int}dt=0$ for any integer $n\ne0$.) [Fleshing this out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem), we can (often) write the full integral around a closed path as a sum of multiples of such coefficients. Often, an integral of interest is something easy minus something else easy (indeed, often something equal to $0$).

For example, let's take the $t=0$ case [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem#An_integral_along_the_real_axis), You can prove $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\pi$ by regarding this as the $R\to\infty$ limit of the integral along the diameter of a semicircular contour whose arc is $Re^{i\theta},\,\theta\in[0,\,\pi]$. As $R\to\infty$, the integral along the arc $\to0$ (proof explained in the link). But the integral around the semicircle is$$2\pi i\lim_{z\to i}\frac{z-i}{z^2+1}=\pi$$(once you've understood the theory summarized above); so, subtracting the arc, the original integral is also $\pi$.